# Powershell auto-completion using script file

Tags: windows, powershell, autocomplete

I wanted to execute a PowerShell script file script.ps1 like this:

```
powershell ./script.ps1
```

How will I simulate a 'tab' (auto-complete) feature in script file?

Eg : on the PowerShell prompt, I can do

```
PS> get [TAB]
```

for getting suggestions for commands starts with 'get-'

Same thing : how will I write in a script file, means saving the script.ps1 file like:

```
get-\t
```

and executing `PowerShell ./script.ps1` resulting error instead of getting suggestion for command which starts with "get-"

Any idea to encode the tab event inside a script file to achieve the command auto completion ?

Comment: Not really sure exactly what you want to achieve here. But .. Get-Command -Verb Get ... returns what i believe you are after.

Comment: You cannot do this. Why would you ever want to do this? When you write a script you must explicitly state the specific command that you want to run.

Comment: @Jonas get-command get-* is working.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

powershell get-command get-*
Is working

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you intend to do but here are the basics on tab-completion:

Save the PS1 file then you can type part of the file name and autocomplete will offer it among the suggestions (though this is done in alphabetical order for all possible suggestions that PowerShell knows.)

If you wish to get parameter tab completion you need to enabled the cmdlet (script) or function as an "advanced" function with a Param block which defines all of the Parameters you cmdlet or function accepts.

The typing:   Get-MyCommand -   # will result in the possible param and switch names being offered in turn.

Running PSReadline (available from the PowerShell Gallery an enhance the autocomplete feature for all commands and parameters.

If you are seeking to perform some other function you'll need to edit your question to be more specific and how clear examples....